# Como inserir hora junto com data no c# com sgbd Mysql -

Tags: mysql

utilizo essa linha para salvar a data quando subo algum registro para meu bd

```
 sql = "INSERT INTO ativacao (codigo, nomepc, data) VALUES (@codigo, @nomepc, curDate())";
```

essa é só a primeira linha e funciona muito bem, consigo salvar certinho a data da inclusão daquele registro, mas gostaria de inserir juntamente o horário, la no meu banco de dados já mudei o campo para DATETIME, mas qual seria a função que salva o horário junto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como vc está escrevendo a query, a linguagem da sua aplicação é indiferente. Considerando que a sua coluna `data` esteja no formato correto vc pode utilizar as funções `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` ou `NOW()`, dependendo se quer usar o fuso-horario da sessão ou UTC. Recomendo usar sempre UTC.

Ex: `INSERT INTO ativacao (codigo, nomepc, data) VALUES (@codigo, @nomepc, UTC_TIMESTAMP())`

Para maiores detalhes dessas funções e outras alternativas, pode consultar a documentação do MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html